# Multiple fieldset in a form tag

Tags: forms, input, fieldset

I Wanted to know if a `<form>` can contain many `<fieldset>` in it? Or is it better to use `<div>` instead? In my case, I want to design a sophisticated responsive designed `<form>` with many different kinds of `<input>.' And if so, do the``should be in his own`` alone?

Better like this :

```
        <form action="#" method="POST">

          <fieldset id="input1-wrapper">
            <h3>Input 1</h3>
            <input type="texte" name="input1" placeholder="input1">
          </fieldset>

          <fieldset id="input2-wrapper">
            <h3>Input 2</h3>
            <input type="texte" name="input2" placeholder="input2">
          </fieldset>

        </form>
```

Or like this :

```
        <form action="#" method="POST">

          <div id="input1-wrapper">
            <h3>Input 1</h3>
            <input type="texte" name="input1" placeholder="input1">
          </div>

          <div id="input2-wrapper">
            <h3>Input 2</h3>
            <input type="texte" name="input2" placeholder="input2">
          </div>

        </form>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Multiple Fieldsets in a form are allowed. Example: Data entry fields in one `fieldset` and `action buttons` ('submit,' 'cancel' etc.)  in a separate fieldset.

Fieldset should always have a **legend** tag according to the standards.

Actually, `Fieldsets` are just another 'display' block level element. i.e. think of it as a 'fancy div'. It can be used anywhere a 'block level element' can. It has no 'special knowledge' of what is inside it. As the 'legend' is a separate element that it can be styled individually with CSS.

being pedantic ;-/

[www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/forms](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/forms.html)

Extracted text: ' ..., one can use the fieldset element. The title of such a group of controls is given by the first element in the fieldset, which has to be a legend element.'.

It looks a lot nicer that a 'div' with headings, in my opinion. To the point that I use it outside of forms for grouping things. Try getting that text in the border with CSS.

```
 <form action="#" method="POST">
    <fieldset id="input1-wrapper">
       <legend>Input 1</legend>
       <input type="text" name="input1" placeholder="input1">
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset id="input2-wrapper">
       <legend>Input 2</legend>
       <input type="text" name="input2" placeholder="input2">
    </fieldset>

 </form>
```

Comment: @Floradu88, thanks for the correction - would have been nice if i was 'pedantic' and 'correct'! :-)

Comment: The `legend` element is optional: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-fieldset-element