# I can' t make the second fieldset appear

Tags: html, css, fieldset

Hi guys I wanted to ask a question, I was doing the FCC survey exam and while I was adding some inputs in the second fieldsets I noticed that the page doesn't let me see it.. any advise?

```css
body {}

label {
  display: block;
  margin: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title> Whats your favourite videogame?</title>
  <link rel="stylessheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="title"> WHATS YOUR FAVOURITE VIDEOGAME?</h1>
  <p id="description"> Please fill up the survey to help find the most popular videogames </p>
  <form id="survey-form">
    <fieldset>
      <label>Name: <input id="name" type="text" required /></label>
      <label>Age (optional): <input id="age" type="number" min="10" max="120" /></label>
      <label>Email: <input id="email" type="email" required /></label>
      <label>What do you do for living?
    <select id="job">
      <option value""> (Select one) </option> 
      <option value"1"> Student </option>
      <option value"2"> Full time job </option>
      <option value"3"> Prefer not to say </option>
      <option value"4"> Other </option>
 </fieldset>

<fieldset>
      <label>How much do you play? <input type="text">  
</fieldset>  
</body> 

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- It's just because you are missing to close many elements in your code.
- Morover you do not need to wrap your `input` in `label` tags, `html` has `for` attribute with `label` tagw which help you to link, `label` with correct `input` field. The only logic is `id` attribute of that `input` should match with the `for` attribute of `label`.
- And please be careful while closing tags you are starting the tags but not closing them that's the reason your second `fieldset` was not appearing. and also visit [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22732248/multiple-fieldset-in-a-form-tag#:%7E:text=Multiple%20Fieldsets%20in%20a%20form,tag%20according%20to%20the%20standards.) for more knowledge.

```css
body {}

label {
  display: block;
  margin: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title> Whats your favourite videogame?</title>
  <link rel="stylessheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="title"> WHATS YOUR FAVOURITE VIDEOGAME?</h1>
  <p id="description"> Please fill up the survey to help find the most popular videogames </p>
  <form id="survey-form">
    <fieldset>
      <label for="name">Name: </label><input id="name" type="text" required />
      <label for="age">Age (optional):</label> <input id="age" type="number" min="10" max="120" />
      <label for="email">Email:</label> <input id="email" type="email" required />
      <label for="job">What do you do for living?</label>
      <select id="job">
        <option value ""> (Select one) </option>
        <option value "1"> Student </option>
        <option value "2"> Full time job </option>
        <option value "3"> Prefer not to say </option>
        <option value "4"> Other </option>
      </select>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
      <label for="money">How much do you play?</label> <input id="money" type="text">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```